# I have a problem with the button, downtime, after click

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
       <div class="col-md-3 text-right">
           <button type="submit" id="ok" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Submit</button>
       </div>
```

The application can be accessed by multiple users working in separate profiles, solution I need is that after clicking on a button by specific user, that same button must be blocked for the next 5 seconds. So not every user can click a button at the same time.

Comment: What have you tried and why you think it did not work? Please explain all the details.

Comment: That's going to take quite a bit more than a little code. You would need the server to broadcast a message to its clients telling it to disable the button. This is certainly possible, through the use of technologies like SignalR and the like, but it may be worth considering a different design.